# Sending S/MIME encrypted emails through SendGrid SMTP

Tags: email, encryption, smtp, sendgrid, smime

I am setting up a WordPress site that will send S/MIME encrypted emails via SendGrid using a plugin called WP PGP Encrypted Emails (looks like it uses PHP's openssl_pkcs7_encrypt). I have successfully sent, and decrypted S/MIME emails with my hosting provider's postfix SMTP servers. However I have to take into account deliverability, so I would like to use SendGrid (which is not a changeable requirement for me) to improve their deliverability.

The issue that I am running into is that first SendGrid's API will reject emails that have the content-transfer-encoding set to "base64". I don't know how significant this header is in the context of S/MIME emails, but whenever I remove it or change it, my emails don't come through as expected. I did some research and found that the API simply doesn't allow changing this header, but that I should be able to modify the content-transfer-encoding header if I send directly to SendGrid's SMTP at smtp.sendgrid.net. If I do that, I can indeed send out an email that arrives with an encrpyted attachment, as expected. The problem is that when I try to decrypt the attachment in Outlook (another requirement), I get a message saying that "the underlying security system cannot verify your Digital ID".

My questions are whether or not anyone has encountered this issue before and been able to resolve it, do SendGrid SMTP servers allow content-transfer-encoding to be modified, and what role does this header play in sending and recieving S/MIME encrypted emails?

Edit: Email Headers

```
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.5.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you include an example of the headers of such an S/MIME encrypted E-Mail in your question?

Comment: @not2savvy Sure, I've included a subset, I'm not sure if there are any others that might be relevant.

Comment: The headers in your questions look good (assuming the line breaks are correct). Especially, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` is correct in this context. I suspect that the error message "the underlying security system cannot verify your Digital ID" means that SendGrid is trying to perform some additional verification. Do you use self-signed certificates? I'm sorry, I haven't implemented directly with SendGrid, but we have a software that sends encrypted emails over a server function that uses SendGrid without problems, so I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Good catch yes we are using self-signed for dev testing.

Comment: My guess is that SendGrid tries to verify the certificate used to encrypt the email, which fails because it's self-signed, so SendGrid finds no trusted root. However, I wonder why SendGrid attempts the verification at all. I would expect that there is an option to turn this behavior off. Unfortunately, when browsing the docs, I find only mention of domain authentication.

Comment: Are you able to send the email like this to a different inbox and decrypt the contents?

Comment: @philnash I wound up not trying that, because I found out I could successfully send through SendGrid SMTP from my hosting provider. After encountering issues I had moved over to testing on a site copy on my local XAMPP server. Something about that environment must have been causing an issue, but I'm still not sure why a carbon copy of the site on a local host would corrupt the Digital ID.

Comment: That is weird, though I’m glad it’s sorted for you now.